# Pandas creating variable from nlargest sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a variable based on the sum of a group and the nlargest sum of the group.

The function for the variable is as follows:

```
new_var = ((((.78 * group_sum) - ((sum of 2 largest values of SHOW column in group)+value of row))/(value of SHOW column in row))/3)+1
```

Here is  a sample df and code I  have tried:

```
test_data = {'group': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'SHOW':[100,100,300,400,100,100,100,400,500,200]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = test_data)

df['new_var'] = ((((.78 * df.groupby('group')['SHOW'].transform(sum)) - (df.groupby('group')['SHOW'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2).sum())+df['SHOW']))/df['SHOW'])/3)+1

df['new_var'] = ((((.78 * df.groupby('group')['SHOW'].transform(sum)) - (df.groupby('group')['SHOW'].nlargest(2).sum(axis = 0)+df['SHOW']))/df['SHOW'])/3)+1
```

The first code I tried returned all NaN for the new_var, the second code returned incorrect values.

Comment: What are the correct values?  So, we can verify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you added the expected correct values to your question?   Try:

```
grp = df.groupby('group')['SHOW']

df['new_var'] = ((((.78 * grp.transform('sum')) - ((grp.transform(lambda x: x.iloc[:2].sum()))+df['SHOW']))/(df['SHOW']))/3)+1
```

Output:

```
   group  SHOW   new_var
0      1   100  2.600000
1      1   100  2.600000
2      1   300  1.311111
3      1   400  1.150000
4      1   100  2.600000
5      2   100  3.380000
6      2   100  3.380000
7      2   400  1.345000
8      2   500  1.209333
9      2   200  2.023333
```